# How to create a gradient using a line and rgb values

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter-canvas

I am attempting to create a program where the user enters the start and stop point for the gradient rgb values, and then as gradient created using a line that moves one pixel and changes color slightly. However my output is giving me a line ( see image)

[image: example of line output]

Here is an excerpt from my code that controls the gradient

```
canvas = drawing_panel(500,300, "white")
width = 500
height = 300
x_color1 = 50
x_color2 = width
y_color1 = 0
y_color2 = 0
red = 0
green = 0
blue = 0
start_red = int(input("Start red? "))
red = start_red
start_green = int(input("Start green? "))
green = start_green
start_blue = int(input("Start blue? "))
blue = start_blue
stop_red = int(input("Stop red? "))
stop_green = int(input("Stop green? "))
stop_blue = int(input("Stop blue? "))


steps = int(input("How many steps have you walked? "))


red_change = (stop_red-start_red) / width
print(red_change)
green_change = (stop_green-start_green) / width
print(green_change)
blue_change = (stop_blue-start_blue) / width
print(blue_change)


def gradient(start_red,start_green,start_blue,stop_red,stop_green,stop_blue):
    global x_color1
    global x_color2
    global y_color1
    global y_color2
    global red 
    global green 
    global blue


        
    while globalbool:

           
        canvas.draw_line(x_color1,y_color2,x_color1,y_color1+height, (red,green,blue))

        
        y_color1 = 0
        y_color2 = 0
        x_color1 +=1
        x_color2 -=1

        red += red_change
        green += green_change
        blue += blue_change
```

Comment: Where are you importing the drawing panel from? As it is the code won't run, you need to provide a [mre]

Comment: What are the values you input to have the result?  BTW, avoid using console inputs with GUI application.